# Magento 1.8 add to cart Querystring

Tags: magento-1.8, product, cart, custom-options

I can't figure out how add a product to the cart via a "querystring" with custom options in  Magento 1.8. CE I do know about the form key but that hasen't helped me yet.

Here's what I have tried! But it always goes back to the product page and tells me that I have not provided the required option.
  http://mydomain.com/checkout/cart/add/product/8/qty/2/options[1]/2/form_key/1tIQKeqKeloqlBzL/

This on the other hand takes me to the shooping cart, but it's empty when I get there.
http://mydomain.com/checkout/cart/add?product=[9]&qty=[3]&options[1]=[3]&form_key=[1tIQKeqKeloqlBzL]

Has someone solved this?

Comment: Are your custom options set to required or is this a wrong behaviour? I guess the product page shown with required options is correct if you have custom options required.
Maybe this could help you: http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract.html#getAddToCartUrl

Comment: Where are you getting that fork key value from? Isn't it different for every session? I am trying to solve a similar problem where I need the form key in order to add a simple product to cart.

Comment: Have you tried to log the POST request magento sends to the cart with FireBug?

Comment: @Amasty No that might do the trick ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the code from the build in Wishlist module, that stores the `$buyRequest` variable. Actually it contains the custom options from the post/get request.

See `app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php` , method `_addItemToWishList` and then `cartAction` function.